# What is the output of thic C code? I need explaination

Tags: c

```
int main() 
{
    char boolean[][6]={"TRUE","FALSE"};
    printf("%s",boolean[(unsigned int)-1 == ~0]);
}
```

After executing, I get it as FALSE. What is the reason?

Comment: You should ask whoever wrote this code why they would place "TRUE" at index 0 and "FALSE" at index 1. Since it makes as little sense as `#define TRUE 0`.

Answer (score 11):

Because

```
~0 == 0xffffffff  (the ~ operator inverts all bits)
```

and

```
(unsigned int)-1 == 0xffffffff
```

as

```
(0xffffffff == 0xffffffff) == 1
```

your expressions boils down to

```
boolean[1]
```

which results in

```
"FALSE"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a mental trick.

```
(unsigned int)-1 == ~0
0xffffffff == 0xffffffff
1
```

and `boolean[1]` points to `FALSE`, so the output is correct.

But in your mind, the condition expands to `true` so why is the output `FALSE`?

Answer: The ordering of elements in the `boolean[]` array is wrong or at least not what it should be to give the expected results.

It's along the lines of

```
#define TRUE 0
#define FALSE 1
```

and then wondering why the C compiler "ignores" the "new rules" for truth values and code suddenly becomes buggy and convoluted.

Comment: The only valid definition for FALSE is `#define FALSE ('-'-'-')`. TRUE can, of course, safely be defined `#define TRUE ('+'+'+')` which immdiately ends the bad habit of comparing a condition to TRUE.